# why when i use ً character in crystal report all space replace that character?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm beginner in crystal report,i have problem,i use crystal report in my project 
and use the Persian language in that,every thing is ok,but when user enter the `ً` 
character,my report export to me this:
[image]

but when i delete `ً` character,show me this and correct format:
[image]

what happen?thanks.

Comment: I cant understand persian...can you translate how it is showing in report and how should you need in report

Comment: @Siva when user use character ً  (for example 1161) all report SPACE character replaced with ً